# How to customize/style woocommerce account page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

As you can see here: https://wildlatina.com/my-account/

the white body is not inside the page and there is not margin padding for the login form? what did I do to mess this up? I'm a beginner when it comes to editing with css so please go easy on me. Just would like the account page to look nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi please login to your cpanel or ftp then open your theme style.css

find the css rule below

```
.full-width-content .container.grid-container {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

and comment the rule like this

```
.full-width-content .container.grid-container {
  /*max-width: 100%;*/
}
```

and it will look like this

[image]

Comment: so commenting will change it back to normal?

Comment: yes, or you can remove it as well but for future, you just need to comment it.

Comment: Here is the style.css file: https://mega.nz/#!3Y8AiSLR!39wWlMWgJTAYkZ7OeU_cpgLXRusSXUCU2rewuebcu9I

Comment: I have sent you updated style.css link please upload the code on your original style.css but first make a copy of the style.css

Comment: i worked :) i hope that when my theme updates that it stays the same

Answer (score 0):

You have used the Wordpress theme GeneratePress.  In that theme, if you have the class `container` and `grid-container` on an element, the width of that element is reset from 1080px to `auto` - which, in your case, means it fills the width of the page.  So, your DIV with id "page" is changed from 1080px to the width of the page.

You should remove the `container` class from this DIV.  You may then have to add some styles back to get the final effect you desire.

Comment: i orginally used css hero for that page, so im guessing the plugin ruined the page, i uninstalled the plugin but the page still loosk weird. also it says i shouldnt edit the style.css file look: https://mega.nz/#!3Y8AiSLR!39wWlMWgJTAYkZ7OeU_cpgLXRusSXUCU2rewuebcu9I

Answer (score 0):

Hello You Can Style It By Using Some Plug-ins Which present at plug-ins>new one 
for example you can go with this plug-in
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-login-and-registration/

If You Cant Style It Please Post The Error You Are Getting Neatly And Most Probably You Can Use Wordpress Login For Woo-commerce But If You Are Really Interested To Use Only That You Can Customize It From CSS Or You Can Use Plug-ins Which Do The Same But No Coding Knowledge Required To Do It From Plug-in Because Everything is Graphically Done And whatever The Coding Part Is That Will Be Take Cared By Plug-in Itself So Maximum Use Plugins So It Could Better In Development

Comment: as per your question this will sure helps you but if you are getting still error , no issue i can fix it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

1) you can add this css add into theme or child theme style.css

```
.hfeed.site.grid-container.container.grid-parent{
width: 80%;
}
```

2) you can remove **container** class Here:

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed site grid-container container grid-parent">
```

my suggestion is second option is right

Comment: number 1 didnt work, here is the style.css file: https://mega.nz/#!3Y8AiSLR!39wWlMWgJTAYkZ7OeU_cpgLXRusSXUCU2rewuebcu9I

Comment: give !important and try it and use use any catch then clear it.